# Kotlin compiler issue with overriding of Java final function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

I’m dealing with following issue with Kotlin/Java Compiler.
Imagine following scenario: let `First` be a Java class with a final function and `Second` be a Kotlin class extending `First` with a function of the same name like the final function in `First` class, example:

```
// Java class
class First {
    final void foo() { }
}
```

```
// Kotlin class
class Second: First() {
    fun foo() { }
}
```

Obviously, it’s wrong because the final function `foo()` can not be overridden. However, compilation pass successfully and in run-time I get `java.lang.LinkageError: Method void Second.foo() overrides final method in class First`.
Is this correct behavior of compiler? I supposed that there will be some validations for this case. Thank you!

Comment: Unable to reproduce with kotlin 1.3.20. I get a build error saying `'foo' hides member of supertype 'First' and needs 'override' modifier.`. If I add that modifier, I get the error `'foo' in 'First' is final and cannot be overridden`.

Comment: What version of kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin version is 1.3.50

Comment: final methods should not be overridden, so the error is completely correct

Comment: @PaulienVA Yes, but I would expect it rather during the build, not in the runtime.